# Joining Table that Contains Multiple Value in One Field with another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am joining a table that has multiple values in one field. I don't get the result that I want to from the query. I want to join tables using the groupid and I want to make a result of name and group name(s).

tbPerson

| personid | name | groupid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | Alpha | 1,2,3 |
| P002 | Beta | 2,3 |
| P003 | Charlie | 1,3 |

tbGroup

| groupid | group_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Investor |
| 2 | Distributor |
| 3 | Retailer |

I want to join them to make a table like

| name | group_name |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | Investor, Distributor, Retailer |
| Beta | Distributor, Retailer |
| Charlie | Investor, Retailer |

```
SELECT p.name, g.group_name
FROM tbPerson p 
LEFT JOIN tbGroup g ON p.groupid = g.groupid
```

It only gives 1 group_name for each person.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT tbPerson.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(tbGroup.group_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS group_name
FROM tbPerson
JOIN tbGroup ON FIND_IN_SET(tbGroup.groupid, tbPerson.groupid)
GROUP BY tbPerson.personid
```

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Code-only answers are considered poor. Explain how this answers. But this question is clearly a beginner duplicate, requent duplicate answers should be closed & not answered. [ask] [answer] [Help]

Comment: thank you very much @philipxy for giving me such useful information about images. I will keep it in mind from the right now.

Comment: This post is forever, for others. Please consider editing to improve it.

Comment: Yes sure will do

Comment: This worked perfectly, the FIND_IN_SET nailed it. Thank you so much.